# How can I display the selected row of an MYSQL table into a sample table of an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to add selected data row from mysql db into a html table.
In fact i can select data and show it in console but I don't know how to add it in html page.
**here is my js code**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //Select all customers and return the result object:
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send query results to the client with socket.io. Then you can add results to your html in the client. Suppose your 'customers' table has the following structure:

```
name varchar(20)
password varchar(20)
```

and you have empty  element in your html. You can emit 'customers' event in the server:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, results, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    // we only send results as we know the fields
    socket.emit('customers', results); 
  });
```

And in the client's code (pug or jade):

```
script.
   let socket = io();
   socket.on('customers', data => {
       for (let i = 0, max = data.length; i < max; i++) {
           document.getElementById('customers').innerHTML += data[i].user + ' ' + data[i].password + '<br/>;
       }
   });
```

If you don't know the table fields (it is hardly possible, isn't it?) you can use both `results` and `fields` returned by the query as in the following example:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const mysql = require('mysql');

let con = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mydb'
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connected');

    socket.on('show', () => {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM customers', (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            //we send both: results and fields here as we don't know the fields
            socket.emit('customers', {results: results, fields: fields});  
        });
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('server listening on *:3000');
});

app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index');
});
```

index.pug:

```
doctype html
html
head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
body
    style.
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
        #mysql {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    div
        h3 Query results
        button(id='show') Show
    #mysql
    script.
        let socket = io();
        socket.on('customers', data => {
            let mysql = document.getElementById('mysql');
            let table = document.createElement('TABLE');
            mysql.appendChild(table);
            let tableHead = document.createElement('THEAD');
            table.appendChild(tableHead);
            let tr = document.createElement('TR');
            tableHead.appendChild(tr);
            for (let i = 0, max = data.fields.length; i < max; i++) {
                let th = document.createElement('TH');
                th.width = '75';
                th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.fields[i].name));
                tr.appendChild(th);
            }
            let tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
            table.appendChild(tableBody);

            for (let i = 0, max = data.results.length; i < max; i++) {
                let tr = document.createElement('TR');
                for (let k = 0, max = data.fields.length; k < max; k++) {
                    let td = document.createElement('TD');
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.results[i][data.fields[k].name]));
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', () => {
            socket.emit('show');
        });
```

Here we retrieve information about the fields of the table from `data.fields` and use it in building the table. So we only have to have access to the database and know the name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTTP server, you can use the node `http` package but there are multiple frameworks which will make your life easier to do such tasks efficiently and safely.

I will explain how to it basically with express.js and the jade template engine. 
You will need jade and express dependencies. So in your project folder: 
`npm i express jade --save`

You will need to create a views folder which will contain your jade templates. Here is the project structure.

```
/node_modules
/views
    index.jade
index.js
```

First file

```
// index.js file
// Create an express app
const app = require('express')();

// Create your mysql conn
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
   host: "localhost",
   user: "root",
   password: "",
   database: "mydb"
});

// set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// create a route handler, GET/
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // fetch your mysql data
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // pass your data to your template file
        res.render('index', {data: result});
    });
});

// open your mysql connection and start express app
con.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   //Select all customers and return the result object:
   app.listen(8090);
});
```

Your template file

```
// /views/index.jade
each d in data
  p
    = d.someproperty
```

This is very basic application but it will give you an understanding of how to create a basic http server, get data from your server and display it.

Note that there is also another way, which is to create a REST api and return your data as JSON and display it in a static website making an AJAX call.